# I encrypt data with 32 byte length using AES algorithm the result(cipher text) is 64 byte length,Is this valid?

Tags: java, security, encryption, bouncycastle

I implement this via java , BouncyCastle Provider
use Block mode = ECB and Padding mode = PKCS7Padding

I noticte that if i encrypt data that has 32 byte length(such as 61626162616261626162616261626162 which is hex value of abababababababab) i get 64 bytes length cipher text(f21ee0564ebd5274e10bf4590594b1e16a19592b917b19ee106f71d41d165289) is this cipher text valid? from what i read it look like if you encrypt less than 32 byte length data the algorithm will padding it to 32 byte length and produce a 32 byte length cipher text but if you put in exactly 32 byte length data shouldn't you receive the 32 byte length cipher text ,also if i put in data with more length than 32 byte it will padded to 64 byte cipher text correctly

this is what my code look like :

```
    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainText, byte[] keyBytes)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {

    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);

    return cipherText;
}
```

thx for your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing hexadecimal characters and bytes. Two hexadecimal characters can be used to represent a single byte. So your input is likely 16 bytes and your output then becomes 32 bytes. AES is a 128 bits = 16-byte block cipher.

PKCS#7 padding is defined to pad 16 byte block ciphers. To make sure that the last byte of the plain text is not mistaken for padding, PKCS#7 padding always pads. This means that in the unfortunate circumstance that the plain text is dividable by 16, it will add an entire block of padding. The padding consists of a string of bytes indicating the length of the string in each byte, so for your case the padding consists of the following bytes, represented by hexadecimals: `10101010101010101010101010101010`.

Note that the default provider of Java uses `"PKCS5Padding"` instead of `"PKCS7Padding"`. Both are identical, although PKCS#5 padding officially is only for 64 bit = 8 byte block ciphers. Bouncy Castle will accept that string as well, so it is better to specify `"PKCS5Padding"` for the sake of compatibility.

There is no padding specified for AES that would use 32 bytes as it is only a 16 byte block cipher. It would make sense for Rijndael-256 which is a 32 byte block cipher, but that algorithm hasn't been standardized by NIST and should therefore be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The PKCS7 padding is explained here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Byte_padding

It adds between `1` and `blockLength` bytes, all of which are equal to the size of the padding. This means your message will be padded by 16 16's, creating a 32-byte message that gets subsequently encoded with AES.

Note that your message is 16 bytes, not 32.

In general, a padding of zero length is never used, because it cannot be distinguished from non-zero padding (and the padding must be done in a reversible fashion).

Comment: Modded down as your answer is incorrect, see my answer to understand why.

Comment: @owlstead but 32 bytes _do_ get padded to 64 bytes. A slight modification was made so that I don't claim the OP's message _is_ 32 bytes

Comment: How do you explain an increase by 32 bytes with padding? There are at most 16 bytes of padding since AES has a blocksize of 128 bits or 16 bytes.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Not if padded to 32-byte blocks. Note that it's impossible to delete an accepted answer.

Comment: If you have 32 byte blocks, then it's not AES.

Comment: @CodesInChaos removed the mention of AES. I'm not saying anything incorrect now.

Comment: @JanDvorak The *question* explicitly mentions AES. Also note that if you count hexadecimals, that the poster makes rather unfortunate mistakes with the given number of characters/bytes.

Comment: @owlstead I can't delete the answer. What do you suggest?

Comment: Most parts of this answer are still correct. The only incorrect part is the second sentence of the second paragraph, where particular sizes are discussed. The parts saying that the padding will never be zero length and so if the plain text size is exactly divisible by the block size means you will get a full block of padding are still relevant.

Comment: @owlstead I've edited the figures to reflect the correct amount

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've edited the figures to reflect the correct amount

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever halved the figures. Thanks for the idea ;-)